# How to resolve result null when choose multi image from gallery

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a project for selecting multi-image from a gallery, but `imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex)` return null. Can you help me? It took me a week to fix but not yet.

```
//This is code select muti image from gallery:
public void capturedCamera1() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
        }
    }
}

//this is result after select image:
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri URI = data.getData();
        if (URI == null) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                    ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    mArrayUri.add(uri);
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                        imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);// return null
                        if (imageEncoded == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "imageEncode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            arrayAddInsurrance.add(new ItemAddInsurrance(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageEncoded)));
                            cursor.close();
                            apdapterAddInsurrance.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        if (imageEncoded == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "imageEncode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            arrayAddInsurrance.add(new ItemAddInsurrance(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageEncoded)));
                            cursor.close();
                            apdapterAddInsurrance.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            String[] FILE = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI,
                    FILE, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "CURSOR NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FILE[0]);
                ImageDecode = cursor.getString(columnIndex); return null
            }
            if (ImageDecode == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Bitmap n = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageDecode);
//bitmap decodeFile but ImageDecode null
                arrayAddInsurrance.add(new ItemAddInsurrance(n));
//add bitmap into recyclerview
                apdapterAddInsurrance.notifyDataSetChanged();
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

`cursor.getString(columnIndex)` Returns Null Whereas the URI is not null.

Can you help me? It took me a week to fix but not yet. I feel stress because of it. Can path no true. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@171998f1
                                                                     0 {
                                                                        _data=null
                                                                     }

Comment: I want to show muti image recyclerview when select from gallery but imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex) return null

Comment: No, I want to using recyclerview. add muti image 1 times

Comment: I don't use imagview, but imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex) null, you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a project for selecting multi-image from a gallery

Your code does not have to involve a gallery. Anything can support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. The `Uri` values that are returned do not have to be from the `MediaStore`.

> I don't know how to resolve this.

Stop querying the `MediaStore`. Hold onto the `Uri` values, and pass them to your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) when your `RecyclerView` needs to display those images. As it stands, beyond your existing problem, your `BitmapFactory` code:

- May crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` (if the user chooses too many images or images that are too large) and
- Will be very slow to get there, freezing your UI while you load all of these images to bitmaps

If you only want to deal with files, stop using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and switch to some form of [file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). You will still want to use an image-loading library for the memory and threading issues, but you will be able to limit the user to local files, rather than anything else that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` might support (e.g., Google Drive, Windows file servers).

Comment: hi you, I still do not understand. can you give me example about it or link refer. thanks